# How to specify owner/group in maven assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a build process set up via jenkins which includes assembling a tarball. Since jenkins runs as a jenkins user on the system, this means the files are owned by that uid/gid. So when I unpack the tarball on another system, the files are owned by a random user (or no user at all).

I'm aware I can set permissions so it's not a problem (and I don't forsee a way around this aside from telling users to use --no-same-owner when unpacking). But having arbitrary uid/gid ownership still seems ugly and I'm trying to figure out a way to specify a user, even if it's root, for the files inside the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Some parameters have been added to the maven-assembly-plugin for that purpose:

- `<overrideGid>`: Override of group ID in archive type which can store it.
- `<overrideGroupName>`: Override of group name in archive type which can store it.
- `<overrideUid>`: Override of user ID in archive type which can store it.
- `<overrideUserName>`: Override of user name in archive type which can store it.

These are available starting from the "3.3.0" version of the plugin.

Some additional links:

- the current plugin goal's documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html
- the original feature request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-922
- the associated merge request on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/maven-assembly-plugin/pull/15